# Geode native client deserialise PdxInstanceImpl

Tags: gemfire, spring-data-gemfire, geode

I have a REST client that populates a Geode region with Json data which the Geode REST API automatically converts to a PdxInstance type.

The region triggers a C# native client listener `AfterCreate(EntryEvent<TKey, TVal> ev)` in which the `TVal` type `ev.NewValue` is seen as type `PdxInstanceImpl` and looks like:

`PDX[7534066,__GEMFIRE_JSON]{@type=MyClass, Field1=Value1, Field2=Value2}`

I've seen from [here](https://pubs.vmware.com/vfabric5/index.jsp#com.vmware.vfabric.gemfire.6.6/developing/data_serialization/program_application_for_pdx.html) that the following code can get at the individual Pdx fields

```
IPdxInstance pdx = (IPdxInstance)ev.NewValue;
pdx.GetField("Field1");
```

and that works on a Field level, but I want to convert the `PdxInstanceImpl` that is received to `PdxInstance` so it can be put into another region directly, or I want to convert all the fields back to Json (as a string) in 1 go and put a Json string into another region, or use it as I like.

So there is apparently a way to autoserialize a `PdxInstance` to `MyClass` but if I try

`MyClass c = (MyClass)pdx;`

then I get `System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Apache.Geode.Client.Internal.PdxInstanceImpl' to type 'MyClass'`

I've seen from some [Java client examples](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.gemstone.gemfire.pdx.internal.PdxInstanceImpl) you can use type `PdxInstanceImpl` to get at the data but in the C# native client that gives an error: `PdxInstanceImpl is inaccessible due to its protection level`.

I've added the [autoserializer](http://gemfire-native.docs.pivotal.io/geode/dotnet-caching-api/dotnet-pdx-autoserializer.html) and the results are the same.

Any idea what I am missing here? Thanks

Comment: pdx.GetObject() causes `{System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Object.GetType()
   at Apache.Geode.Client.ReflectionBasedAutoSerializer.deserializeFields(String o, IPdxReader reader)
   at Apache.Geode.Client.PdxWrapper.FromData(IPdxReader reader)
   at Apache.Geode.Client.Internal.PdxHelper.DeserializePdx(DataInput dataInput, Boolean forceDeserialize, Int32 typeId, Int32 length)
   at Apache.Geode.Client.Internal.PdxInstanceImpl.GetObject()}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I've used a field by field approach:

```
IPdxInstance pdx = (IPdxInstance)ev.NewValue;
pdx.GetField("Field1");
pdx.GetField("Field2");
pdx.GetField("Field3");
etc...
```

Outside of the event handlers, to create a PDX instance I used:

```
IPdxInstanceFactory writer = Setup.g.GetCache().CreatePdxInstanceFactory("myType");
writer.WriteString("String", "s");
writer.WriteChar("Char", 'c');
writer.WriteDouble("Double", Convert.ToDouble(1000));
IPdxInstance pdx = writer.Create();
```

To read a PDX instance its:

```
IPdxInstance pdx = Setup.gpg.GeodeGetPdx("myType", key);
MyType t = new MyType();
t.String1 = (string)pdx.GetField("String1");
t.Int1 = (int)pdx.GetField("Int1");
t.Date1 = (DateTime)pdx.GetField("Date1");
etc...
```