# How to serialize an object to Geode

Tags: apache, serialization, geode

I'm still quite new to apache geode...

I currently put objects in geode region using `fromData(IPdxReader)` and `toData(IPdxWriter)` and I write/read line by line.

I need to add a new object, that is hundreds of lines long.

How to serialize a whole object without serializing it line by line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At:

```
private void HandleCreateAndUpdate(EntryEvent<TKey, TVal> ev)
```

Option 1:

```
IPdxInstance pdx = (IPdxInstance)ev.NewValue;
AutoBooker qb = (AutoBooker)pdx.GetObject();
```

Option 2:

```
AutoBooker qb = (dynamic)ev.NewValue;
```

Comment: There's another way to serialise [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45568028/geode-native-client-deserialise-pdxinstanceimpl)